# Is it possible to write `\left(` `\right)` in one command?

Tags: amsmath, preamble

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\pr}{\left(}{\right)}

\begin{document}
$\pr{x,y}$

\end{document}
```

I found the commands `\left(` `\right)` quite flexible and hence useful; but I am not sure how to write them in one command. The attempt shown above has proved wrong.

Comment: Use `\pr*{x,y}` if you want `\left` and `\right`, after properly defining `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\pr}{(}{)}`. Of course you *don't* need `\left` and `\right` in this case. And there are several reasons for not generally using them: use them only when they are *really* necessary, which means quite rarely.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `\newcommand` to define new command and fit with what you want:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand{\pr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document}
\pr{x,y}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very much I thank you. :) That works perfectly well.

Comment: @GudsonChou you're welcome :)

Comment: @GudsonChou It *doesn't* work perfectly; look at the spacing when you use `\pr{x,y}` in context.

Comment: @egreg Have you a way to avoid this using `\newcommand`? I don't have it `:/`

Answer (score 9):

Contrary to your opinion, `\left` and `\right` are quite *rigid* and unflexible: they don't provide the right size in many cases. The usual example is a summation, where

```
\[
\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k} \right)
\]
```

produces too large delimiters. The right size in this case is obtained with

```
\[
\biggl(\, \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k} \biggr)
\]
```

Here's a visual comparison: left the `\left`-`\right` version; note the `\,` for avoiding the clash, which should also be used after `\left(` anyway.

[image]

This said, you're free not to follow the advice. In this case, define properly `\pr` and use the `*`-variant

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\pr}{(}{)}

\begin{document}
$\pr*{x,y}$

\end{document}
```

Of course in this case the parentheses don't grow, so there's no point in using `\pr*` instead of `\pr`. Here's the output of `$\pr*{x,y}\quad\pr{x,y}$`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What in your opinion is the most flexible command without sacrificing spacing? Thanks.

Comment: @GudsonChou Using `\pr` as defined is good; just don't use the `*` when it's not necessary. You also have `\pr[\big]` for slightly bigger parentheses, for instance.