# Is it possible to shorten the use of \left and \right?

Tags: math-mode, equations

So I'm writing a latex document that has the following code in it

```
\begin{align*}
    n! - k &= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{r}\right\rfloor}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{n}{r,\dots,n-ir} ((r-1)!)^i(n-ir)!\frac{1}{i!}\\[1em]
    &= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{r}\right\rfloor}(-1)^{i+1} \frac{n!}{(r!)^i(n-ir)!}((r-1)!)^i(n-ir)!\frac{1}{i!}\\[1em]
    &= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{r}\right\rfloor}(-1)^{i+1} \frac{n!}{r^i(n-ir)!}(n-ir)!\frac{1}{i!}\\[1em]
    &= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{r}\right\rfloor}(-1)^{i+1}\frac{n!}{r^i*i!}\\[1em]
    &= n!\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{r}\right\rfloor}(-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{r^i*i!}\right)\\[1em]
    &= n!\left((-1)^0\frac{1}{r^0*0!}-\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{r}\right\rfloor}(-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{r^i*i!}\right)\\[1em]
    &= n!\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{r}\right\rfloor}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{r^i*i!}
\end{align*}
```

I think you would agree with me that it looks disgusting. Generally because it seems to be filled with so many `\left\lfloor <...> \right\rfloor` strings.

Is it possible to define a command that writes `\left` and `\right` for me in the general case? I've read this post here [Is it possible to write `\left(` `\right)` in one command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274007/is-it-possible-to-write-left-right-in-one-command) but it only covers the case when I want to use round brackets. What if I want to use square brackets, vertical bars or ceiling braces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could load the `mathtools` package and use its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro to create a macro called, say, `\floor` as follows:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor\lfloor\rfloor
```

and replace all instances of `\left\lfloor\frac{n}{r}\right\rfloor` with `\floor{\frac{n}{r}}`. (For more information on the uses of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, please see section 3.6., "Paired delimiters", in the [user guide](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) of the `mathtools` package.)

And, since there are quite a few instances of `\floor{\frac{n}{r}}`, it's useful to create a shorthand macro for them, say,

```
\newcommand\flnr{\floor{\frac{n}{r}}}
```

In addition, I would replace all instances of the multiplicative `*` with `\,`, i.e., thinspace. Also, use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` for the large parentheses in rows 5 and 6, as the parentheses produced by `\left(` and `\right)` are too large from a purely typographic/aesthetic perspective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor\lfloor\rfloor
\newcommand\flnr{\floor{\frac{n}{r}}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
n!-k 
    &= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\flnr} (-1)^{i+1} \binom{n}{r,\dots,n-ir} ((r-1)!)^i(n-ir)!\,\frac{1}{i!}\\[1ex]
    &= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\flnr} (-1)^{i+1} \frac{n!}{(r!)^i(n-ir)!}((r-1)!)^i(n-ir)!\,\frac{1}{i!}\\[1ex]
    &= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\flnr} (-1)^{i+1} \frac{n!}{r^i(n-ir)!}(n-ir)!\,\frac{1}{i!}\\[1ex]
    &= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\flnr} (-1)^{i+1}\frac{n!}{r^i\,i!}\\[1ex]
    &= n!\biggl(1-\sum_{i=1}^{\flnr} (-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{r^i\,i!}\biggr)\\[1ex]
    &= n!\biggl((-1)^0\frac{1}{r^0\,0!}-\sum_{i=1}^{\flnr} (-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{r^i\,i!}\biggr)\\[1ex]
    &= n!\sum_{i=0}^{\flnr} (-1)^{i}\frac{1}{r^i\,i!}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick q: why do you use `\biggl` and `\biggr` instead of left and right? Also, I noticed that the floor braces don't span to the bottom of the fraction. This can be a problem because if the fraction was bigger, then the floor braces would not fit. I think this is on me because I provided a poor example of code.

Comment: I have essentially the same code, but with `\floor{n/r}`, which is much less intrusive. I'd also recommend `!\,` when the factorial is followed by something that doesn't add space by itself.

Comment: @Kookie - Because the parentheses produced if `\left(` and `\right)` are *too big* relative to what's optimal from a typographic point of view. For more on this topic see, e.g., [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173771/5001) to the query [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001). [Shameless self-citation alert!]

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, [also, I really don't mind self-citation. A source is a source lul.]

Comment: @egreg - I agree whole-heartedly on using inline-fraction notation instead of `\frac`. For the answer shown above, this may be achieved by defining `\flnr` not as `\newcommand\flnr{\floor{\frac{n}{r}}}` but as `\newcommand\flnr{\mathclap{\floor{n/r}}}`. On adjusting the spacing if `!` (the factorial symbol) is followed by `<something>` (other than `)`, right?): Note the use of `\,` in the first three rows to provide a visual breather between `(n-ir)!` and `\frac{1}{i!}`. I failed to mention this change explicitly in my write-up, though. :-(

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 6):

My proposal is almost the same as Mico's, but with some significant differences:

1. use `n/r` instead of `\frac{n}{r}`;
2. add `\,` when a factorial is followed by another object to be multiplied with (if that object doesn't produce space by itself, like in the last line);
3. two instances of nested parentheses are dealt with using `\bigl` and `\bigr`;
4. no additional vertical space is necessary (due to the `n/r` in the upper bound of summations).

I endorse the proposal of avoiding `*` for multiplication and substituting it with `\,` in those denominators; it's not generally necessary, these cases seem to want it, mostly because of the same letter in the exponent and in the following symbol.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
n! - k 
&= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\floor{n/r}}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{n}{r,\dots,n-ir} 
          \bigl((r-1)!\bigr)^i(n-ir)!\,\frac{1}{i!}
\\
&= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\floor{n/r}}(-1)^{i+1} 
          \frac{n!}{(r!)^i(n-ir)!}\bigl((r-1)!\bigr)^i(n-ir)!\,\frac{1}{i!}
\\
&= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\floor{n/r}}(-1)^{i+1} \frac{n!}{r^i(n-ir)!}(n-ir)!\,\frac{1}{i!}
\\
&= n! - \sum_{i=1}^{\floor{n/r}}(-1)^{i+1}\frac{n!}{r^i\,i!}
\\
&= n!\,\biggl(1-\sum_{i=1}^{\floor{n/r}}(-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{r^i\,i!}\biggr)
\\
&= n!\,\biggl((-1)^0\frac{1}{r^0\,0!}-
            \sum_{i=1}^{\floor{n/r}}(-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{r^i\,i!}\biggr)
\\
&= n!\sum_{i=0}^{\floor{n/r}}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{r^i\,i!}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Looks great, thanks for the advice! Maybe this is just a style thing, but I'm not a big fan of inline maths.

Comment: @Kookie Two-story fractions are really big; they're necessary for clarity in the main parts, but when superscripted they're generally better treated with the slashed form, provided numerator and denominator are simple.

Comment: Ok, I will consider using inline math a little more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\qty` from `physics` and `\binom` from `amsmath`, here's how they work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    S &= \qty(\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k})\\
    S &= \qty{\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}}\\
    S &= \qty[\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `physics` package also helps with writing down matrices a little bit more easily with `\mqty`. You just need to write `\mqty`, then use the delimiters you want `()`, `[]`, or `{}`, then, write whatever you like. Separate each column with `&` and each row with `\\` just like in a usual array.

Comment: Do you know where I can find documentation for this?

Comment: Yes, here's the documentation for the physics package: [link](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf) with \qty at page 2 and \mqty at page 7

Here's amsmath's user guide: [link](http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) with \binom being at page 16

The physics package is one of my favorite, it simplifies so many things and adds really useful commands for physics majors/physicists

Comment: Wau! The physics package is awesome! Although I am not studying physics, it contains commands to bold symbols and shortens things like derivatives. My mind is blown really. Thanks for showing me both guides!